# Android duplicate file copied in APK xmlschema.dtd

Tags: android, android-studio, duplicates, apk

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK javax/servlet/resources/XMLSchema.dtd

```
File1: C:\Users\gupta\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.servlet\servlet-api\2.5\5959582d97d8b61f4d154ca9e495aafd16726e34\servlet-api-2.5.jar
File2: C:\Users\gupta\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.mortbay.jetty\servlet-api\2.5-20081211\22bff70037e1e6fa7e6413149489552ee2064702\servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar
```

I have found on answers on duplicate files copied in APK license
but my question is different. So if anyone has suggestions then please help me

Gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
         compileSdkVersion 25
         buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
         defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.guptavishal1291.youtubefreesub"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
        }

    }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        exclude module: 'httpclient' //by artifact name
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' //by group
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient' //by both name and group

    })
    compile group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client-extensions', version: '1.6.0-beta'

    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev183-1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.22.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.22.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: i have different case than others, they have problem related to license.txt Duplicate files copied in APK javax/servlet/resources/XMLSchema.dtd

Comment: help me with this as i cannot proceed further with my project

Comment: if u want any other code to check ask me and i will provide

Comment: Try to **clean** and **rebuild** or **invalidate cache and restart**